# testing result of $.post with json_encode

Tags: posts, javascript

I have this javascript code :

```
$.post(url, { 'ids[]': row_ids },function(response)
```

for information post execute this :

```
echo json_encode(array('success'=>true,'message'=>$this->lang->line('items_successful_deleted')));
```

When I debug I found that the response contains this :

```
"Array(    [0] => 4555){"success":true,"message":"Vous avez supprim\u00e9 avec succ\u00e8s"}"
```

I just want to test if success equal true but when I do it like this : `if(response.success === true)` it doesn't work.

I just wanna know to accede to values of response.

Comment: did you try in your encode line to put true in apostrophes as well?

Comment: yes i did but it doesn t work

Comment: check `typeof response` to see if really is a `json object`

Comment: Have you tried using `response[0].success` instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the value of your JSON response in JS, you need to parse the JSON object you're returning before trying to access any values:

```
jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);
if (jsonResponse.success === true) { /*do something*/ }
```

Comment: i did it but i had error while JSON.parse(response); i think response isn't on right json format

Comment: Actually, what is the error that's coming up when you try to JSON.parse ? You'll definitely need to parse it before accessing it in JS

Comment: Actually it looks like your function is returning an 'echo' of the data rather than the actual data.

Change your PHP function to 'return json_encode' instead of 'echo json_encode'